# saveInBackground (Parse) throwing an error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I am having an issue in the following swift code, using `Parse-Server` to save data online.

```
let xxDico = ["N8": "Eight", "N5": "Five"],
    upLoadParseUnit = PFObject(className: "numberClass",
                               dictionary: xxDico)

print("xxDico : \(xxDico.count)")

upLoadParseUnit.saveInBackground {
    (succeeded:Bool, error:Error?) in
    if succeeded {
        print("\(#function) succeeded!!")
    } else {
        if error?.localizedDescription == "NAME-USED" {
            // A record previously existed with the same name.
            print("\(#function) did not succeeded!!\nError: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        print("Error(1) in \(#function)\n" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
}
```

And this is what I get in the debugging console:

```
xxDico : 2
Error(1) in executeUpLoad(_:)
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

This seems simple, but what am I doing wrong to get this error?
And what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I don’t know anything about parse but at least for Apple errors you often get a more detailed error message if you do `print(error)` rather than using localizedDescription

Comment: Do you see the data being saved via dashboard? What do you see on your server logs?

Comment: No the data was not saved. But I finally found the issue. I was the MONGODB_URI string which had been tampered with on my server.